# Failed to create functions during sam deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, amazon-efs

I am creating a project in *cloud9* with *AWS Lambda* and *Amazon EFS* resources so that users can use a machine learning model.

I was able to build the project successfully, but no matter what I do, `sam deploy --guided` fail and error message is:

```
Error: Failed to create/update the stack: sam4-app, Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" at least once.
```

In the aws cloudFormation console, I found that the creation of my two functions failed

[image: cloudFormation]

I am sure I am doing something wrong, yet after so much struggle I have not been able to identify my mistake.

Do I need to make any changes inside the [template.yml](https://github.com/RISEIT-IS/MLInference-Lambda-EFS/blob/main/template.yml) in order to use AWS Lambda?

It is important to mention that I am taking as reference [multiple machine learning models for inference on AWS Lambda and Amazon EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-multiple-machine-learning-models-for-inference-on-aws-lambda-and-amazon-efs/)

Also I have dumb question, I am using *windows* inside *cloud9*, could this be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use too much memory. You are trying to provision 5000MB for your function. While a limit of [10GB is now possible](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-supports-10gb-memory-6-vcpu-cores-lambda-functions/) in *some* regions, it isn't supported in all regions. In the regions where 10GB is not supported, the old 3008MB limit applies.